# Time complexity Big Oh using Summations

Tags: for-loop, big-o, time-complexity

Few questions about deriving expressions to find the runtime using summations.
The Big-Oh time complexity is already given, so using summations to find the complexity is what I am focused on.

[image: First Example]

So I know that there are 2 instructions that must be run before the first iteration of the loop, and 2 instructions that have to be run, (the comparison, and increment of i) after the first iteration. Of course, there is only 1 instruction within the for loop. So deriving I have 2n + 3, ridding of the 3 and the 2, I know the time complexity is O(n).

Here I know how to start writing the summation, but the increment in the for loop is still a little confusing for me.
Here is what I have:

[image: Summation 1]

So I know my summation time complexity derivation is wrong.
Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `n / 2` on the top and `i = 1` on the bottom:

[image]

The reason it's `i = 1` and not `i = 0` is because the for loop's condition is `i < n` so you need to account for being one off since in the summation, `i` will increase all the way up to `n / 2` and not 1 short.

Comment: Okay thank you that really helps! so just to reiterate, lets say the loops condition was i <= n, would I leave i = 0?

Comment: @Amateur_Haskell Yup that's right.  p.s. make sure to accept the answer if this answered your question :)